# When using not selector, do I need to specify the parent again?

Tags: jquery

I need to select (n+2) rows from a table except the 4th row.

For that, which of the following jQuery selector is correct?

```
$("#table_id tr:nth-child(n+2)").not("tr:nth-child(4)")
```

*OR*

```
$("#table_id tr:nth-child(n+2)").not("#table_id tr:nth-child(4)")
```

Although both give the same result, is there any difference between them?

What I really want to know is:

Do we need to specify the parent once again in the `.not()` selector when using it, or just the corresponding descendant element specified in the beginning?

Comment: so, does that mean that when using `.not()` I'm automatically referring to the children of the same parent?

Comment: I tried to explain better in the answer below.

Comment: you have already your answer inyour question, don't you?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using the $() function you have a jQuery object in return.

The .not() function is applied to the returned object. This means that the not it is like a filter for the elements contained on the jQuery object.

You may take a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/not/